# Symfony 2 - findall() too many DB queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

why Symfony2 performs 40 DB queries if I use following code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$records = $em->getRepository('MyWebBundle:Highlight')->findAll();
```

I thought that `findAll()` method returns only all items from Highlight entity and associations to other entities replaces Proxy objects. But now `findAll()` method gettings all associations entities.

Do you know where is the problem ?

**indexAction**

```
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $records = $em->getRepository('MyWebBundle:Highlight')->findAll();

    $csrf = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
    $token = $csrf->refreshToken(self::FORM_TOKEN_ID);

    $params = array(
        "data" => array(
            "all" => $records,
        ),
        "token" => $token->getValue(),
        "static" => array(
            "add" => $this->generateUrl("admin_highlight_add"),
            "edit" => $this->generateUrl("admin_highlight_edit"),
            "del" => $this->generateUrl("admin_highlight_del"),
        ),
    );
    $ser = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $jsonContent = $ser->serialize($params, 'json');

    return array('jsonContent' => $jsonContent);
}
```

**Highlight entity**

```
namespace My\WebBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * Highlight
 *
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("none")
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\WebBundle\Entity\HighlightRepository")
 */
class Highlight {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="abbreviation", type="string", length=8, unique=true)
     */
    private $abbreviation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="color", type="string", length=7)
     */
    private $color;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Goods", mappedBy="highlight")
     */
    private $goods;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Calibration", mappedBy="highlight")
     */
    private $calibrations;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->goods = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->calibrations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set abbreviation
     *
     * @param string $abbreviation
     * @return Highlight
     */
    public function setAbbreviation($abbreviation) {
        $this->abbreviation = $abbreviation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get abbreviation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAbbreviation() {
        return $this->abbreviation;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Highlight
     */
    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set color
     *
     * @param string $color
     * @return Highlight
     */
    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get color
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getColor() {
        return $this->color;
    }

    /**
     * Add goods
     *
     * @param \My\WebBundle\Entity\Goods $goods
     * @return Highlight
     */
    public function addGood(\My\WebBundle\Entity\Goods $goods) {
        $this->goods[] = $goods;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove goods
     *
     * @param \My\WebBundle\Entity\Goods $goods
     */
    public function removeGood(\My\WebBundle\Entity\Goods $goods) {
        $this->goods->removeElement($goods);
    }

    /**
     * Get goods
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getGoods() {
        return $this->goods;
    }

    /**
     * Add calibrations
     *
     * @param \My\WebBundle\Entity\Calibration $calibrations
     * @return Highlight
     */
    public function addCalibration(\My\WebBundle\Entity\Calibration $calibrations) {
        $this->calibrations[] = $calibrations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove calibrations
     *
     * @param \My\WebBundle\Entity\Calibration $calibrations
     */
    public function removeCalibration(\My\WebBundle\Entity\Calibration $calibrations) {
        $this->calibrations->removeElement($calibrations);
    }

    /**
     * Get calibrations
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCalibrations() {
        return $this->calibrations;
    }

}
```

**Highlight repository is empty**

Comment: You said it performs 40 queries. But what are theses queries ?
Are they all the same ? Can we have th Highlight entity ? As well as the repository ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reaction. Highlight has OneToMany associtation to Goods. Goods has OneToMany associtation to Calibrations. These queries are for getting these association entites. But I want to get only all Highlight items.

Comment: That's why I would like you to update your question with entites definition as well as Highlight repo's code ;)

Comment: Now is my question updated. I added Highlight entity, indexAction, which performs 40 DB queries. If I commented line with `$em->getRepository('MyWebBundle:Highlight')->findAll();` One query is performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the serializer. Since you serializer highliths, each of them has their properties serialized as well which means that lazy query will be performed to retieved Goods which will be also serialized.

You should then prevent this behaviour by adding annotations to highlight's goods property as this

```
use ...
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\SerializerBundle\Annotation\Exclude;

/**
 * ...
 * @ExclusionPolicy("none")
 */
 class Highlight
{

   /**
    * ...
    * @Exclude
    */
   private $goods;

}
```

You can have further details about exclusion stratigies from [JMSSerializer doc](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies)

Comment: Yes, the problem was in serializer. I added annotations and now it is ok. Thanks very much :)

Comment: No problem, was a pleasure

Answer (score 1):

findAll itself does not perform many queries. Queries are executed when you access related entity via getters. As relation are not fetched eagerly, they first time are fetched when you are acessing them.

I think serializer access all children to send your object.

See [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-lazy-loading)

> Whenever you have a managed entity instance at hand, you can traverse
>   and use any associations of that entity that are configured LAZY as if
>   they were in-memory already. Doctrine will automatically load the
>   associated objects on demand through the concept of lazy-loading.

To prevent this either disable children serialization or use fetch EAGER or build a DQL query, which prefetch all the children alongside with parents, like (just sample, not valid DQL)

```
SELECT Highlight, Good, Calibration
FROM Highlights Highlight
LEFT JOIN  Highlight.googs Good
LEFT JOIN  Goog.calibrations Calibration
WHERE ...
```

Comment: The problem was really in serializer and I solved this problem adding annotations for exclude relation entites. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yeah. Always think of lazy loading. It's a good thing while you think about it. Once forget you'll get thousands of requests :)